# samsung s4 has suddenly started calling through Skype instead of the local network

Tags: calls, skype

My samsung s4 has suddenly started calling through Skype instead of the local network. I have not set any defaults. I have also uninstalled skype, it still goes through skype, then stops then I have to call again then it goes thtough the network. How can resolve this? please help

Comment: When you say, "I have also uninstalled skype, it still goes through skype, then stops," could you explain precisely what you see happening?

Comment: it chooses skype to call. It shows the skype call view and then returns to keypad screen. when I call the second time it then goes through normal.

Comment: If a Skype window is coming up, Skype must still be installed.

Comment: Thats the thing..it is not! and thts wat is driving me mad! I have uninstalled skype

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it just went in NSA mode. You can check in *Settings->Apps*, switch to the "All" tab, and slowly and carefully check the entire list whether Skype really has been removed (it should no longer be found here then).

If you find it there, make sure to really uninstall it. If it will not leave in peace, you can make it leave in pieces:

If you not already have one installed, get yourself a *terminal emulator* (e.g. [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)). Open it, and enter:

```
pm uninstall com.skype.raider
```

This advices the "package manager" (pm) directly to remove this app.

If nothing of the above helps, please [edit your question](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/49271/edit) and add some details: Is your device rooted? Do you have an ADB setup available?

---

If your device is rooted, you can directly check for the app without the help of GUI elements. Via `adb shell` or above mentioned Terminal Emulator (lines starting with a `#` are comments and do not need to be typed):

```
# become root. This will popup a confirmation box, confirm:
su
# now we look for the data directory of the Skype app
ls /data/data | grep skype
```

If the prompt returns without any information, there is no Skype data directory. If it, however, returns something like `com.skype.raider`, the data directory is still there. Still being root, you can also check for Skype's `.apk` file:

```
ls /data/app | grep skype
```

If Skype is still there, this should yield something like `com.skype.raider-1.apk`. You can also list the packages known to the system, which does not even need root:

```
pm list packages | grep skype
```

And you could see if root powers help accomplishing what failed with the error message you described, and re-issue a

```
pm uninstall com.skype.raider
```

With ADB available, you could do all this in a much more convenient way from your computer:

```
adb shell
su
```

Then continue as described above. Note: If `su` was successfull, the command prompt should be prefixed by a `#`, otherwise it remains prefixed with a `$`.

Comment: Hi izzy
Checked all apps carefully. Skype not there. 
Did the terminal emulator.  I get a message saying "failed to connect to dumpstate service. Killed"

Now wat?

I dnt know wat u mean by is ur device rooted? Do u have adb set up?

Comment: Please see the [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) for clarification on the root part, the [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for ADB, and [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) for how to get it (if you mind). On a rooted device, and ADB available, you have many additional options to find out and solve. One more question: Have you already restarted your device after uninstalling Skype?

Comment: Ok.let me c wat I can do with rooting and adb. Thnkx

Comment: Yes I did restart after uninstalling

Comment: OK. I've updated my answer with additional hints on what can be done with root/ADB. If nothing else helps, you still have one last ressort: doing a factory-reset. But after that, you would have to install and configure all your apps again. Well, most of them at least.

Comment: Thnkx soo much izzy. I dnt knw wat had happened. After 2 days it automatically started working fine. I jus hope the problem doesn't return! Thankx for your effort!!

Comment: Glad the issue is gone! So though it did so automatically, you might consider "accepting" the answer (click the checkmark left to it) if it at least proved helpful. To upvote, you need some more rep first for yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to uninstall Skype. Go to Setting/Application Manager. You will get Skype as one one of tha Apps. Click on Skype. Launch by default, clear default.